# Express-Can't access JWT token in middleware

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

My verifyToken function is:-

```js
function auth(req, res, next){
    const token = req.header('auth-header');
    console.log("token", token);
    if (!token) return res.status(401).send("Access Denied");
    try{
        const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
        req.user = verified;
        next();
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(400).send("Invalid Token");
    }

};
```

Login  and verification function is:

```js
exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    if (!user) return res.status(400).send("Username doesn't exist");

    const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!validPass) return res.status(400).send("Invalid Password");

    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id, name: user.fullName }, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
    res.header('auth-token', token);
    res.send("loggged in!");
};

exports.verify = (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("Verifed");
};
```

Routes

```js
router.post('/login', users.login);
router.get('/verify', auth, users.verify);
```

I am getting logged in successfully but whenever I use 'verifyToken' middleware it returns "Access Denied" due to undefined token. How do I access the token in my middleware?

Comment: req.header is not a function

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have used res.header

Comment: whats `console.log("token", token);` showing? show the routes which call the auth middleware

Comment: @LawrenceCherone sorry it's 'res'. I have edited the code. Still same problem though. How can I access the token in my middleware?

Comment: check token is being sent..

Comment: Yes, I the token is being set in the header. Checked with postman

Comment: If you're using jwt, it should be in the header with key `Authorization`. Here is the documentation. https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: @Danizavtz `Authorization` returns undefined too.

Comment: Can you put the code from your client side code? html file show the function that you are  making the request.

Comment: Actually I  haven't made client side. Just testing through console.log and postman @Danizavtz

Comment: Can you post complete code from the server?

Comment: @Danizavtz updated

Comment: I need see complete files, to check require, functions and libs you're using.

Answer (score 0):

try: const token = req.headers.authorization

Comment: the token is  printed as undefined